# Formatting Result Type of Query Result in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

MYSQLI has the option to specify the reulttype of the queries fetched from the DB.

mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype);

I wanted to know if there is a similar option when using CodeIgniter framework. It seems to return an ASSOC Array by default whereas I needed a MYSQLI_NUM type array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No, CI does not have an option to return a MYSQLI_NUM type array.

It isn't very difficult to restructure CI database returns to get the structure you want.

Assuming you will often want to get MYSQLI_NUM type array results create a function in your model called `result_num_array()` It will restructure the output of any CI database function that returns a `CI_DB_result`. Those functions are `db->query()`, `db->get()`, and `db->get_where()`. The return from any of these can be the argument passed to the `result_num_array()` which is defined this way.

```
public function result_num_array($query)
{
  $data = $query->result_array();
  $result = [];
  foreach($data as $record)
  {
    $row = [];
    foreach($record as $field)
    {
      $row[] = $field;
    }
    $result[] = $row;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

A usage example: In the fictional model function `get_some()` use `result_num_array()` like so

```
public function get_some()
{
  $query = $this->db->query("Select * from sometable");
  return $this->result_num_array($query);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes a lot of sense